# Attempted import error: 'useForm' is not exported from 'react-hook-form' (imported as 'useForm'). When using Next + amplify + react query

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, tanstackreact-query

I'm using

- NextJS version 14.1.4
- @tanstack/react-query 5.28.8
- aws-amplify 6.0.23

So there are guides on how to setup NextJS with react-query. They would say to make the provider that's initializing react-query a separate file and to attach "use client" on top. I did just that but, whenever I start the server and attempt to load any page, it throws the error:

```
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react-core/dist/esm/components/FormCore/FormProvider.mjs
Attempted import error: 'useForm' is not exported from 'react-hook-form' (imported as 'useForm').
```

As reference:

Here's my layout.js

```js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "../app/ui/globals.css";
import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import "../app/ui/globals.css";
import Provider from "./providers/providers";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <Authenticator.Provider>{children}</Authenticator.Provider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Here's my providers.jsx

```js
"use client";
import awsconfig from "@/app/aws-exports";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import { useState } from "react";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
export default function Provider({ children }) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient());
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

I'm also questioning if my placement of `Amplify.configure()` is correct, because if so, I'd have to use it on every page.jsx file?
For example:

```js
"use server"
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { HydrationBoundary, QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { listInfluencer } from "@/app/server/actions";
import ClubsComponent from "@/app/ui/dashboard/clubs/clubs";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "@/app/aws-exports";
import { dehydrate } from "react-query";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig, { ssr: true }); <-- I have to place this on every page.jsx?

const ClubsPage = async ({ searchParams }) => {
  const q = searchParams?.query || "";
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey: ["listInfluencers"],
    queryFn: listInfluencer({
      filter: {
        creatorType: {
          eq: "club",
        },
      },
    }),
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrate(queryClient)}>
        <ClubsComponent />
      </HydrationBoundary>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any help to solve this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Update the question to include where `useForm` is used.

Comment: by the way, you don't need this `"use server"`

Comment: I don't use `useForm`. It is done by react-query's QueryClientProvider

Comment: It's not QueryClientProvider. But because aws's Authenticator. Move it to <Provider>

Comment: You mean moving `<Authenticator.Provider>` inside provider.jsx file?

Comment: I have tried moving `<Authenticator.Provider>` and `Amplify.configure(awsconfig);` inside provider.jsx and it still yields the same error.